# ARKit large model follows camera instead of staying stationary

Tags: swift, arkit

My code looks for a QR Code in the frame received during the session(didUpdate) ARSCNViewDelegate method. I check to see if all four corners and the center of the QR Code are in the same plane with hitTest, and then drop an ARAnchor at the center. I create a SCNReferenceNode for the anchor with a reference to a scenekit model of a fairly large house (70'w x 30'd x 30'h) I position the house 30 meters in front (z =-30) and 30 meters to the right (x=30) of the detected QR Code, and it initially appears OK. However, if I try to "walk around" the model, it moves with me, always maintaining a constant distance and offset from my iPad camera.  I have tried using my own anchors, the plane anchors created by ARKit, and lots of other ideas, nothing changes. How can I get it to stay put, like the plane model does in the boilerplate ARKit xcode project?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like although you created some new anchors, that you perhaps didn't assign your model to them? So when your model gets loaded and presented, it's being 'tracked' on the gyro. So you get that Pokemon Go effect where regardless of what you do the AR model doesn't change in size.

Comment: I assign the SCNReferenceNode to the anchor via the delegate method node: for anchor: that is called after I add the anchor to the session. Is there another (or better) way? And it isn’t a size change issue, the model actually tracks the camera. I haven’t heard about objects being tracked on the gyro, can you elaborate? That sounds like something to investigate.